# Implementing a "Follow" user feature using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, memcached

**Issue:** I am working on a kind of e-commerce platform which has sellers and buyers.Now in my case a seller can also be a buyer i.e every user can buy plus sell.
So i have a single table called **users**.Now I want to implement a follow vendor/user feature,wherein the user can click **follow** and he sees all the goods listed by that vendor under his account(till he unfollows).

Now my traditional approach was to have a table that has a key and two columns to store the **follower and the followed** Eg:
      `|id | userId| vendorId`
 So it will go horizontally as the users go on following others.But if I have a user following many people(say **100**) my query may take a lot of time to select a 100 records for each user.

**Question:** How can I implement the follow mechanism?Is there a better approach than this?I am using PHP and Mysql.

**Reasearch:** I tried going through how facebook and Pinterest handle it,but that seemed a bit too bigg for me to learn now as I don't expect as many users immedeately. Do I need to use **memcache** to enhance the performance and avoid recurring queries?Can I use a **Document Database** in any sense parallel with Mysql?

I would like a simple yet powerful implementation that would scale if my userbase grows gradually to a few thousands.

Any help or insights would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you thought of using comma separated values for storing the vendor names like id| userId| vendorId1, vendorId2, vendorId3 and so on

Comment: @Sid how on earth would that improve performance?

Comment: @user1615903 A single column to hold a string with vendor names could improve perfomance, maybe. For example you wouldn't have the data in various pages but all in one place. But it would make controling the data integrity harder and could slow the performance.  And it would make searching for users who obserce a vendor nearly impossible. Probably it's not worth all the trouble but it's possible it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, from my understanding of this scenario, a user may follow many vendors, and a vendor may have many followers, this constitutes a many<->many relationship, and thus the only normalised way to achieve this in a database schema should be through using a link table, exactly as you described.

As for the performance considerations, I wouldn't worry too much about it, since it could be indexed on userId and vendorId, the queries should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.Yes it is a many to many relation and I was planning to go by the same approach,but I wonder how it is handles by sites like Pinterest,twitter.May be I need it later. :P Any other smart algo or way to achive it?

Comment: Simple is smart ;)
For what you've described, this is the simplest solution. Jakub's advice on clustered indexes is also definitely worth taking into consideration, but other than that, I wouldn't want to over-think this problem too much

Answer (score 2):

The junction table is probably the best approach but still a lot depends on your [clustered index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_index#Clustered).

- Table clustered with a key on the substitute key id can make adding new records a bit faster.
- Table clusetered with a key (userId,vendorId) will make the queries where you look for vendors a certain user follows faster
- Table clustered with a key (vendorId,userId) will make the queries where you look for users that follow a certain vendor faster