# Scaling a database horizontally using PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, nosql

**Problem statement:** I am working on a application in which a user can follow other users  (like twitter or other e-commerce sites) and get their updates on his wall.It is in relation to a merchant and a user. A user can follow any merchant.The user himself can be a merchant,so actually its like a user following other users(Many-many realtion).

**Issue:** The easiest way to go about it was to have a junction table which will have 
 **id (auto-increment) | follower_user_id | followed_user_id**. But I am not sure when the database grows vertically,how well will it scale.If a user follows 100 people there would be 100 entries for a single user.In that case if I want to get the followers of any user it would take longer time for the query to execute.

**Research:** i tried studying twitter and other websites and DB designs,but they use different databases like graph based Nosql etc to solve their problems.In our case its Mysql.I also went about using caching mechanism but I would like to know,if there is any way I could store the values horizontally i.e each user has his followers in a single row(comma separated would be tedious as I tried it).

Can I have a separate databse for this feature something like Nosql based database (mongo etc). What impact would it have on performnce in different cases?

if my approach of going with the easiset way is right how can I improve the performance for say 5-10k users(looking at a small base now)?Would basic mysql queries work well?

Please help me with inputs over the same.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with horizontal scaling; horizontal scaling is about having multiple mysql servers for load balancing purposes

Comment: Have you done any tests to see how the DB responds with lots of rows? If you use indexes then you can still get a quick response even with millions of rows. Testing with mock data and queries is how I dealt with this issue.

Comment: If you index on `follower_user_id` and `followed_user_id` the queries should be fine. MySQL can handle millions and millions of rows.

Comment: But there should be no issues with having 100 followers per user; mysql can handle extremely large volumes of data without issue - though you don't actually need the autoincremented id in your followers table, just a unique composite index on `followed_user_id` and `follower_user_id` and possibly the reverse as well, depending on your queries

Comment: This question looks surprisingly similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234207/implementing-a-follow-user-feature-using-php-and-mysql) asked a couple of days ago

Comment: @gunnx Indexes in exactly which way..I am using primary and foreign keys to identify records.Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Just as MatthewMcGovern mentioned, indexing those columns should do the job but nothing beats a bit of testing

Comment: @gunnx Actually I was halted before I could try it out.But as suggested I will go and try it and come up if I have issues.Indexing,com[posite keys,going through them!

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you pls elaborate on  how would composite indices help in my case.I tried to go through but they seem to be more related to text and I would be dealing with id's

Comment: Composite indexes are simply indexes on more than a single column, not related in any way to the datatype of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the comments and doing some research I came to the conclusion that it would be better I go the normal way of creating the followers table and do some **indexing** and use caching mechanism for it.

Indexing as suggested **composite** indexes would work well
For **caching** I am planning to use Memcache!

Answer (score 0):

The system I use (my personal preference) is to add a 2 columns on the users, `following` and `followers` and store a simple encrypted json array in it with the ID's of followers and the users that are following..

Only drawback is that when querying you have to decrypt it then json_decode it but it has worked fine for me for almost 2 years.

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend this. The data isn't normalised as you are storing the same piece of information twice, once in the 'following` of user A and once in the 'followers' of user B. This allows more room for error. Not to mention large tasks like say, removing a popular user, will require lots of decoding, removing the ID, encoding again and inserting back into the database. Instead of just `DELETE FROM Relationship WHERE FollowerID = UserID`

Comment: Makes it a lot harder to maintain consistency in your data, requires extra work, writing 2 records rather than one whenever there's a change, larger database volumes, etc

Comment: Was just about to give a comment similar to MatthewMcGovern's with the exact same reasons :D add to that the fact that this approach would make more complex queries far more difficult (for example, if in future you wanted to know 'People who follow merchant X also follow merchant Y'). Keeping your data atomic allows far easier manipulation and querying.